# Html helper in mvc 3 without name attribute

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am working on an application using MVC - 3. I want to create a `textbox` using mvc html helper like:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Title)
```

This will rendered something like:

```
<input id="Title" name="Title" type="text" value="">
```

I want to generate a markup for textbox without `name` attribute. Is there any existing helper with generates a tag without name attibute. I am doing this because i want to exclude some field from form submission. How can i do this ?

Comment: If they should be excluded, don't render them as text boxes.

Comment: i have to render it as text boxes because to keep working client validation

Comment: If it's not going to be submitted, it doesn't need to be validated.  If you've designed things in this way, and you absolutely must do it, you can either ignore it at the other end, or write a new `HtmlHelper` extension method that does everything `TextBoxFor` does, bar giving it an actual `name` attribute.

Comment: name is mandatory if you are using the helpers.The value of the text wont be passed if you are doing http post.model binding process will not recognize it without the name attribute.

Comment: @CodeIgnoto yes i do not want to pass value thats why asking to remove name attribuute

Comment: @user1740381, it might help if you provided more information as to what you're trying to achieve here.  Red flags are always raised when a question is about using standard practices in a non-standard way.  It *usually* points towards a mistake in the design somewhere.

Comment: Already answered here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12311364/how-to-extend-html-textboxfor-to-remove-the-name-attribute

Comment: This is actually a justifiable scenario.  Most payment gateways have some sort of javascript library to tokenize a payment method without you having to post card details to your server.  Removing the name attributes keeps them from posting and then you override with an ajax call to their api to tokenize.